# Is there a way to turn on ifdef/ifeq/else/endif pairing check in makepp file?

Tags: makefile, makepp

I have to debug a huge legacy makepp file which has mismatched ifdef/ifeq/else/endif. I am surprised makepp does not flag any error. The version I use is:
1.50-1009181-09138-0902101

I tried gnumake 4.2.1 and it is able to flag errors. Is there a switch I need to turn on to catch this in makepp?

Comment: Here is [the documentation](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/2.0/makepp_command.html)

Comment: I didn't find any option for this. I am surprised by default it does not check this.